# Editing problem when adding json data in visual studio

Tags: reactjs, json

I'm adding json data to files with React.js, it's ok when there is only one line in the file but when there is more than one line you have to convert it to a single line.Sometimes there are 20 lines of text, what should be done to turn it into a single line? Here are my codes.

trans.js:

```
const Translations = {
   example1:'xxxxx',
   example2:'xxxxxxxxxx',
   example3:'xxxxxxxxx
         xxxxxxxxxxx
         xxxxxxxxxxx',  //For example, the lines here should be single lines.


}
export default italianTranslations;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your trans.js file, you can modify the multi line string by using template literals(``).

Example:

```
const Translations = {
   example1: 'xxxxx',
   example2: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
   example3: `xxxxxxxxx
         xxxxxxxxxxx
         xxxxxxxxxxx`, // Multiline string wrapped in backticks
};

export default Translations;
```

Now, It will be treated as single line when you'll try to access it.

For example, console.log(Translations.example3) will be treated as a single-line string.